# How does this regular expression limit email addresses to ".com" instead of "...com"

Tags: ruby, regex, validation, email

The regex below:

```
EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
```

is what I initially used to validate email format. After finding that the format `"name@email...com"` was passing my tests, I copy/pasted a different piece of regex that limits the amount of periods. This looks like:

```
EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
```

The main difference is the piece of regex below:

```
(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)
```

I can't quite figure out how this bit works. Can someone break it down for me?

Comment: You're doing it wrong and excluding a lot of legitimate domains. The only thing we can presume about email addresses these days is that they contain an `@`. The rest is *extremely* hazy. `x@co` is potentially a valid email address, as is `x@გე`.

Comment: Honestly, given how crazy email addresses are, the best way to validate one is to **try and deliver it**. If it succeeds, it's valid. If it fails, it doesn't matter if it's able to pass a regular expression, it's garbage.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: None of you have answered my question.

Comment: I'm only being stubborn here because many people get email validation **horribly** wrong and this infuriates people with legitimate, standards compliant addresses. Unicode domains are a thing, so having `[a-z]` in your TLD matcher is going to be a huge problem.

Comment: While you might *think* they didn't answer your question, they actually did very well. You can't *validate* an address with a regular expression like you're using. As @tadman said, "try and deliver it" if you want to know whether it's valid. If someone responds it's at least valid; It might not belong to whoever claimed it was theirs, but at least it was valid. Read "[Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)" for a much better discussion.

Comment: See "[Mail::RFC822::Address: regexp-based address validation](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)" if you want a valid pattern for testing an email address. That still won't prove whether the address is good, it'll only test whether the address met the spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that in this subexpression:

```
(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)
```

The character class `[a-z\d-]` does *not* contain a period. The expression requires there to be at least one (`+`) of those characters after the period (`\.)` in order to match.  Therefore, a series of periods with no letters or digits or hyphens between them won't match the repetition of the subexpression.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your regular expression here is that you're allowing for multiple dots:

```
/[a-z\.]+\.[a-z]+\z/
```

To fix this you need to make your repeating pattern more specific in terms of structure:

```
/(?:[a-z]+\.)+[a-z]+\z/
```

That means you can have one or more repeating groups of letters plus dot. That will exclude multiple dots in a row.

Do keep in mind that email addresses are getting increasingly insane with the introduction of new [GTLDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_top-level_domain) that are often used without any sort of prefix. That is, `example@google` may be a valid address in the future. You can't expect there to be a dot in the domain.

Answer (score 0):

You have `[a-z\d\-]+(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)*`. The `[a-z\d\-]+` part ensures that this part of the string starts with a sequence of at least one non-period character. A period is only allowed one per `(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)` structure. In each `(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)`, the period `\.` is necessarily followed by `[a-z\d\-]+`, which includes at least one non-period character. This ensures that whenever a period appears, it has at least one non-period character on the left and on the right. In other words, consecutive periods are not allowed.